# Jenkins [Groovy] Annotation Grab cannot be used in the sandbox

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Following the remarkably terse docs here:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-third-party-libraries

I am trying to use @Grab to access a third party library from Jenkins.

`@Grab(group='org.jsoup', module='jsoup', version='1.13.1')`
 is in a Groovy class in a library. The library is specified in Jenkins/configure 
under Global Pipeline Libraries

> Sharable libraries available to any Pipeline jobs running on this
>   system. These libraries will be trusted, meaning they run without
>   “sandbox” restrictions and may use @Grab.

I am not using the default branch of the library, but I am not sure whether that is relevant to my problem.

When running the pipeline, I get the following error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Annotation Grab cannot be used in the
>   sandbox.  at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.RejectASTTransformsCustomizer

Any hints would be deeply appreciated

Comment: something is a little bit off.. Obviously your library is seen by Jankins in a sandbox environment, but you said you specified it under global pipeline libraries.
Did you find where the issue was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article on russian describes details about it: https://habr.com/ru/post/338032/ 
**Summary**: you need to create separate libarary in SCM and use Grab there.

Comment: that's nice example, but unfortunatelly doesn't address issue in question